# How to avoid frequently file write in Java

Tags: java, performance, file-io

I have the problem:
in a loop, each time I need to write a large string into one file(or temporary file), then process take the file as an argument for the next step.

Something along:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    File f = File.createTmpFile("xxx","xxx");
    // write into f etc. 
    String result = func(f);
}
```

Since I think each time creating a File and writing string into it seem to be much costly, so is there any alternative methods?

Comment: How many bytes are these "large" strings? How many such strings are there? Why do they need to be written to a file at all – can you pass them in-memory instead?

Comment: If you already have the `String` that is to be written to the file, why bother persisting it ?

Comment: What does `func` do? Can you move the file creation outside the loop?

Comment: Why do you need to create so many files in the first place ?

Answer (score 0):

If these Strings do not need to be immediately persisted to a File, you could store them in *memory*, some sort of Collection, e.g. an ArrayList.  And when the list gets "large", say, every tenth time, write all ten at once to a file.  This cuts file creation by 10X.

The danger is that if there is a crash you may lose up to 9 values.